# How can I print "\n" using NSLog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I print "\n" to the console by using NSLog or printf function?

Basically I was trying to print a String with value "Hello\nWorld". My requirement is, I want to print it **AS IT IS**. But when I tried to print, it was printing like,

```
Hello
World
```

not as

```
Hello\nWorld
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Escape it using another backslash.

```
NSLog(@"Hello\\nWorld");
```

Comment: Output is Hello\
World.
Not as I expected.

Comment: @prathumca: I get `Hello\nWorld` as output.

Comment: Surprisingly this is working on Simulator not on iPhone. Why?

Comment: After cleaning all my targets, this seems to be working. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Try "Hello\\nWorld". If you want a literal \ in a string you need to escape it with another \ .

Answer (score 0):

I use C strings (except in the very rare case where I'm debugging something specific to Unicode):

```
NSLog( [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", "Hello\nWorld" ] );
```

Make the above into a macro taking C parameters, and it becomes portable between C and Obj C.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSLog(@"Hello\\nWorld");
```

Output -

```
2013-07-04 21:13:52.913 myProject[7408:303] Hello\nWorld
```